# Varying spritefont quality depending on string

Tags: xna, monogame, fonts

I'm using [Kleymissky font](http://www.dafont.com/kleymissky.font) size 26 made via Nuclex font renderer (Hinting Method: AutoHinter) - [download](http://www.speedyshare.com/TZNPG/Kleymissky26.xnb)

Why the thickness of the font drawn on screen depends on the string itself? What can I do to ensure it'll always be drawn one way or another (but not both)?

[image]

I'm using MonoGame, dll v3.1.2

Comment: How are you centering the text? Make sure your x,y are whole numbers and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @ClassicThunder You're absolutely right, casting horizontal position to int solved the issue! Please make an answer co I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XNA `SpriteFont` class uses the `SpriteBatch` and `Texture2Ds` to back it. Just as when you render any other Texture2D if you use vectors with non whole numbers XNA samples the overlapping source pixels leasing to the unexpected behavior you are experiencing.

To avoid the issue make sure the the you use whole numbers when assigning the location so that the source and destination pixels align.